# boto3 : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ressource

Tags: python, boto3

I'm trying to use boto3 to interact with my AWS infrastructure. 
When I'm using boto3 directly from the python CLI (v 3.6.1) the following piece of code is working :

```
import boto3
client = boto3.ressource('iam')
print(client.User('myusername').arn)
```

However, if I try to use it from a python script file (test.py) I get the following error:

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
client = boto3.ressource('iam')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ressource'
```

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a simple typo to me.

Try

```
boto3.resource('iam')
```

Instead of

```
boto3.ressource('iam')
```

Source: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#service-resource

Comment: Hello, 
Yes ... typo mistake, only one 's'. 

Thanks !